# What is the right way to serve dynamically generated images using Apache and mod_perl?

Tags: perl, apache, apache2, gd, mod-perl

I have an Apache2/mod_perl2 system up and running.

I'm using [GD](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/GD) to create an image on the fly, and I'm then printing it like this:

```
$r->content_type('image/png');
binmode STDOUT;
print $im->png;
```

But is this the correct way to do things in [`mod_perl2`](http://perl.apache.org/)?

(Ignore the fact that I'm generating an image on the fly and not caching it etc ...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under mod_perl2, you should not print stuff directly to `STDOUT`. Instead, use

```
use Apache2::Const 'OK';

$r->content_type( 'image/png' );
$r->print( $im->png );

return OK;
```